# Working with homebrew - command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, path, homebrew

I am working to install homebrew on my Mac and I have had several problems with the PATH. Homebrew is installed, or so I believe. However, any attempt to change the PATH leads to a problem

If I type `brew doctor`, I get the response `-bash: brew: command not found`

However, if I try anything, I get the same response.

e.g. `echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/local/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??`   
which brew`gives me`-bash: which: command not found`

If I try to uninstall brew, using `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

I get `-bash: curl: command not found -bash: ruby: command not found`

I assume my entire PATH is incorrect - how do I get it back to what it should be?

EDITED: `echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/local/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??`, I had made a typo in my earlier post.

EDITED2: I just typed the following `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

This seems to bring back brew, but other functionality is missing
e.g.

```
    /usr/local/bin/brew: line 16: readlink: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/brew: line 17: dirname: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/brew: line 16: readlink: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/brew: line 17: dirname: command not found
```

On top of that `which brew` still gives me `-bash: which: command not found`

`echo $PATH` is currently `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: `echo #PATH gives me a blank` Try `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Good point, I just made an edit, I still get a strange mistake - I get a question mark in the response

Comment: Restart your terminal, this fixes your path hopefully.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it doesn't

Comment: Interesting. Check your `~/.bashrc' and '~/.profile' for some weird PATH changes-

Comment: How do I do that?